# Cannot install App on Android 6.0.1

Tags: android, installation, apk, android-6.0.1-marshmallow

I have some issue installing my App (not through Google Play but just downloading the APK) on devices equipped with Android 6.0.1. It's installing correctly on Android 6.0. The gradle configuration is the following:

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 23
```

The error is: ***cannot parsed the package***. Someone knows if there is some special things to know about the 6.0.1 version ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: Is it one-device problem?

Comment: I've tried on two devices equipped with 6.0.1

Comment: can you tell which devices exactly?

Comment: Cannot tell about that today because the smartphones are on the customer side. Will  get that info tomorrow. But since they are both on 6.0.1, I think that it comes from the OS version. Do you think that setting targetSdkversion to 24 (Android 7.0) will solve the issue ? As 6.0.1 is newer version than 6.0...

Comment: You may try to build a separate apk specifically for Android 6+ with latest targetSdkVersion. Also make sure you use latest build tools.

Comment: @VladMatvienko the devices are Samsung Galaxy S5 and OnPlus equipped with 6.0.1

Comment: Which is the build toolsVersion and compileSdk version

Comment: @Godwin i've edited the post

Answer (score 0):

So According to [this](http://www.technicalnotes.org/fix-parse-error-in-android-there-is-a-problem-parsing-the-package/) page

parsing problem will occur based on

1. Parse error can occur if you have made changes to the app’s manifest file like changing the Android version.
2. It can also occur due to a corrupted .apk file or may because of a partially downloaded apk file.
3. Not enough permission to install third-party apps from unknown sources.
4. Your Android smartphone OS version or the hardware is not compatible with the app.
5. A third-party security application is blocking the app installation.

Comment: I've found this before and tried all of theses points. Just found out that the App is installing on NEXUS 5 with Android 6.0.1 but not on the Samsung S5 and OnePLusOne..